# Trying to create a Bat file to copy single file into a folder that contains multiple folders within folders

Tags: batch-file

I have a file called .nomedia. I am trying to copy it into a folder called Media, and inside Media there are 1000's of folders within folders within folders within folders. I need to paste the .nomedia file to the last folder within all these subfolders. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want the file to be pasted to all folders and subfolders in that directory. If not how do you define last folder?

Comment: Im ok with the file .nomedia being pasted to all the folders and folders within folders within folders etc

Comment: Basically there should be a copy of the file .nomedia in all the folders within Media and 1000's of folders within folders within folders within folders

Answer (score 1):

```py
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

cd /d "f:\Super_User" && set "_source=F:\Batch\source\.nomedia"
for /d /r %%i in (*)do tree /a "%%~fi" | find "\-" >nul||copy "!_source!" "%%~fi\"

endlocal && goto :eof
```

- In conventional formatting:

```py
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

cd /d "f:\Super_User"                   // replace to full path to your root directory 
set "_source=F:\Batch\source\.nomedia"  // replace to full path to you file your file .nomedia

for /d /r %%i in (*)do tree /a "%%~fi"|find "\-" >nul||copy "!_source!" "%%~fi\"

endlocal
```

- For the same in one line in command prompt (in root folder):

```py
for /d /r %i in (*)do tree /a "%~fi"|find "\-">nul||copy "D:\Folder\source\to\your\file\.nomedia" "%~fi\"
```

- Or,...

```py
for /d /r "F:\Super_User" %i in (*)do tree /a "%~fi"|find "\-" >nul||copy "F:\Batch\source\.nomedia" "%~fi\"
```

---

To get the last level of a subfolder, it is only necessary to check if in each subfolder there is another folder there, if not, then copy the file...

You can use a `for /d /r` loop, which will go through all the folders, and in each folder inside the loop, use the `tree` command together with the `find` command, where you can check if the current folder has more subfolders, and when you don't have it, copy your file to the last folder on the level.

- ```py
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```py
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only 
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

You can use the `tree "current_loop_folder" /a` in all subfolders of the loop (recursively) with **`for /d /r`**, and by checking each output with the *find "string"* (**`find "\-"`**) redirecting to the operator **`||`** and take action (**`copy`**) if not found this string `\-` in command `tree` output **`\\---test`**:

```py
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is A0AD-DC56
F:\SUPER_USER\Q1550103
\---test
```

The above output is from the folder where I am, `F:\SUPERUSER\Q1550103` and here we have the `test` subfolder, but if I am in the `F:\SUPER_USER\Q1550103\test` subfolder, I get the output below:

```py
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is A0AD-DC56
F:\SUPER_USER\Q1550103\TEST
No subfolders exist
```

If `find` do not find the string `"\-"`, I have no subfolder in current folder, this is the last folder in current tree:

```py
F:\SUPER_USER\Q1550103\test
```

In this case, if there is no subfolder, the command `tree "Actual_Loop_Folder" /a | find "\-"` command will not succeed, then making the operator `||` execute the `copy` command exactly in your last folder of the actual folder level...

This will try to illustrate how the `||` operator works mechanically:

```py
                    command1 || command2
             execute commad1 || only execute command2 (if) commad1 fails
     if tree folder /a fails || there is no subfolder in it
 there is no subfolder in it || this is the last subfolder
  this is the last subfolder || run copy file .nomedia
tree /a "%~fi"|find "\-">nul || copy"D:\Folder\source\to\your\file\.nomedia"
```

- For more about operator behavior, see linked references below *Conditional Execution*
- Note:  You need edit the path pertinent in **`cd /d`** and **`set _source=`** command:

```py
cd /d "f:\Super_User" && set "_source=F:\Batch\source\.nomedia" &&..... 

:: replace to ::
cd /d "f:\Super_User" // replace to full path to your root directory target

set "_source=F:\Batch\source\.nomedia" // replace to full path to you file your file .nomedia
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[CMD/Bat Operator /dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8123)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: holy S*** This totally works. You are a genius. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

I made this code it seems to work on my tests like you can see in this [video](https://s6.gifyu.com/images/Copiar-para-ultima-pasta.gif).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Filetocopy=C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Copiar para ultima pasta\nomedia"
set "Folders=C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Copiar para ultima pasta"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad "%Folders%" ^|sort /r') do (
Set /a Runs+=1
set "NameA=%%a"
if /i [!Runs!]==[1] Set "NameB="
if /i ["!NameB:%%a\=!"]==["!NameB!"] copy "!Filetocopy!" "!NameA!"
set "NameB=!NameA!\"
)
```

Comment: This solution is faster than mine. Tested!!.

Answer (score 0):

This batch copies a .nomedia file to all 1000+ subdirectories of MYNOMEDIAFOLDERPATH

to show output in console delete >nul in copy command line
to not overwrite existing .nomedia files, replace echo y|copy /-y by echo n|copy /-y

```
set "source=FULLPATHOF.nomedia"
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad "C:\MYNOMEDIAFOLDERPATH\*") do (
  echo y|copy /-y "%source%" "%%~D">nul
)
```

PARAMETERS to change

```
MYNOMEDIAFOLDERPATH  ... full path to your .nomedia file e.g.: C:\mylocaldir1\mylocaldir2\.nomedia
C:\MYNOMEDIAFOLDERPATH\* ... full path to your target directory e.g.: H:\myserverdir1\myserverdir2\*
```

If you have white-spaces in your pathes use "" to enclose the path

**EDIT**
So in your case this should work:

```
set "source=D:\Batch\source\.nomedia"
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad "D:\Batch\Media\*") do (
  echo y|copy /-y "%source%" "%%~D">nul
)
```

Comment: Hi Codebreaker007, Thank you so much for helping me out. I edited the code to the following as mentioned below in notepad, saved it as a bat file and ran it as an administrator but it did not work. Kindly help. Sorry to sound like a noob but thats exactly what I am. ;P I left the overwrite to yes as I dont care if the files are overwritten

Comment: set "source=D:\Batch\source\.nomedia"
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad "D:\Batch\Media\*") do (
  echo y|copy /-y "%source%" "%%~D"
)

Comment: Wouldn't that code posted by Codebreaker007 copy nomedia to every folder inside media rather than only the last folders in the structure?

Comment: See my edit I think you forgot a backslash which makes a big difference ;-)

Comment: Still not working. First I fixed the single quote part you forgot in the for part Media\*") to Media\*"') but it still copies the file to every folder not only the last folders in the structure.https://s6.gifyu.com/images/LastFolder.gif

Comment: Hi codebreaker007 unfortunately it’s not working. :( the backslash was entered correctly. For some reason when I pasted it in the comment section it did not show up. Now when I run the batch file nothing happens.

Comment: Hi Guys. I finally managed. I was missing the ' in the end. Thank you so much. You have just saved me from days of work to just minutes. Codebreaker007 and Ricardo you guys are the best

Comment: @VarunSinghania I don't understand does it actually copy the file to the last folders in the structure for you or was your intention to copy the file to all folders from the begining?

Comment: So I was looking for a solution where it would copy the nomedia file to just the last folder but that is not happening with this code. Its copying the nomedia to all the folders. I am ok with that solution as well as it is solving my problem. But it would be interesting to find a solution where the formula would paste the file to the last folder only