# Delete every subfolder in a directory that doesn't contain certain extensions

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, batch

**Question:** Is it possible to delete every folder in a certain directory that does not contain specific file types for example music files (mp3/flac/wav/etc)?

I've retagged some files using Mp3Tag which also moves them into a new folder structure:

```
\Artist\Album\Artist Name - Album - Track Number - Track.ext
```

[image: Example file structure]

This results in the old subfolders without any music files (mp3/flac/wav/etc) while leaving remnants of `cover.jpg` or `log` files and etc.

So for example, in the image above I want to delete "`\Adele - 25 Album`". Ultimately, I want to delete any subfolders without any music files (mp3/flac/wav/etc).

I've taken some hard stabs at this but I can't really come up with anything fruitful and having a hard time with it too. I wonder if someone could help me with some guidance for this task.

Comment: Rename `f:\!organize` to `f:\organize`. Modify your question to include every music file extension you want to search for and post it this way: `*.aac, *.m4a, ...` Or list the extensions of the files you would like to delete: `*.txt, *.log, *.jpg`. I would prefer an actual `dir /b /s /a-d` in text that represents the directory structure of the problem you are trying to solve. Does something like this occur?: `music103\1.jpg` `music103\6\1.flac`?

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in a previous comment, to keep this simple, it will be best to remove the `!` exclamation mark from any folder names so the PowerShell [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) will work without issue to start.

   > **Note:** Once the cleanup process is entirely complete, you can easily add the exclamation mark back to any folder name(s) as desired if you must.
2. You can then use the below PowerShell script I provided as an example to do what you need it to do for only deleting folders and all folder contents that do not contain the media file extensions you need to keep.

#### Important Items

- You will want to add the specific file extensions to the `$Filter = @("*.aac","*.mp3","*.wav","*.<ext>","*.<ext>","...","...","*.<ext>");` variable at the top of the script so it knows to exclude those directories from the removal process since those contain what you wish to keep folder content wise.
- This process is started first wiping all empty directories with no files or folders within by running `Robocopy <dest> <dest> /S /MOVE` and then once the files are removed from folders not containing the file extensions you wish to keep, it will run this at the end wiping any further empty directories.

### PowerShell

```
$Src = "F:\Organize"
$Filter = @("*.aac","*.mp3","*.wav","*.flac");

Robocopy $Src $Src /S /MOVE 

$AllDirs = (Get-ChildItem $Src -Directory -Recurse).FullName;

$WipeDirs = @();
$AllDirs | % { Process {
    If(!(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$_" -File -Include $Filter -Recurse).DirectoryName){ 
        [array]$WipeDirs += "$_" 
        }
    }};

$WipeDirs | % { Process {
    Get-ChildItem $_ | Remove-Item -Force;
    }};

$AllDirs+$Src | % {
    $nonFilterFiles = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$_" -File).FullName; 
    $FilterFiles    = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_\*" -File -Include $Filter).FullName;

    If($FilterFiles.Count -ge 1){ Return; };
    If($FilterFiles.Count -eq $nonFilterFiles.Count){ Return; };
    If(!$FilterFiles){ $nonFilterFiles | % { Process { Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_ -Force; }}};
    If((!$FilterFiles) -and $nonFilterFiles -ge 1){ $nonFilterFiles | % { Process { Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_ -Force; }}};

    };

Robocopy $Src $Src /S /MOVE
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)
- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [About Assignment Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-6)

  > **`+=`**:    Increases the value of a variable by the specified value, *or
  >   appends the specified value to the existing value*.
- [Remove-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html)
- [Understanding break, continue, return, and exit](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/understanding-break-continue-return-and-exit)

Comment: Josh - I will be happy to make adjustments, etc. and further test if there are any issues. Just explain to me the problem, I will recreate and test, and then edit my answer for a solution. Any further questions, or whatever, let me know—I'm here to help you get this resolved fully.

Comment: Hello Pimp Juice IT. Thanks so much for the assistance. I tried running it in a test folder, but it still has some folders that only contain a "cover.jpg" file.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing in my test folder after running the script you posted above in a .ps1 file.

https://i.imgur.com/QDjkaj6.png

Comment: I tried with your updated script but it still has the same issue as seen above in the Imgur image link. However now it also deletes the .ps1 file. Right now I have a bunch of example files and folders copied to "F:\TEST\Organize" which also has the .ps1 file inside. Running the .ps1 file deletes itself after running.

Comment: I'm okay with the the `!` issue and renaming the folder before running the script. Yeah there are quite a bit of folders that have square brackets which aren't properly deleted by Robocopy, but I don't see any other issues other than that. Thank you for the help... Here's an example of what I'm seeing after running the script in my test folder: https://i.imgur.com/ttNA0oT.png

Comment: @Josh -- Answer updated with the working solution with the script logic I gave you. I tested with the special characters `{ }` and `[ ]` and it works this way with both and removes the files and folders fitting the criteria as you need. I meant to test this many many hours ago and only was able to partially test before being pulled away but I've finish and confirmed where I needed to make these adjustments since I'm done with work now and had time. Glad to help and further adjust still if needed but this seems to do the trick.

Comment: Sorry on the delay. Been busy with life/work. I'll test them out tomorrow after work and post my results.

Comment: @Josh What's up sir! Wanted to circle back around to this as it's a zero vote and non-accepted answer so curious if you have any update on it regarding the latest logic from my example in the answer I provided. Please update me as soon as you get a chance.

Comment: Hey there apologies for just ghosting you. I'll get back to you tonight in regards to this and see how the solution works out for me.

Comment: So I ran your PowerShell code in a .ps1 file that's being called on with a batch file (.bat).

It works deleting the folders that don't have files with the extensions in the filters list, but it also deleted the .ps1 and .bat files that reside in that same folder (currently F:\Organize).

How do whitelist those files from being deleted?

Comment: @Josh - The simplest thing to do here is to add those to the `$Filter = @("*.aac","*.mp3","*.wav","*.flac","*.bat","*.ps1");`. Let me know if this does the trick & I'll update my answer. Another way is like this https://justpaste.it/8u5mz but it's the exact same of just including the PS & batch script extension into the `$Filter` list variable. I have another idea too but I believe you will only have `.ps1` and `.bat` files in the root directory & not in any of the child directories so the first solution may be the best if that's the case. Let me know and I can help more too with some feedback

Answer (score 0):

- Update:

Deleting folder with **`{`** and/or **`[`** in the name, by invoking:

```bat
cmd.exe /s rm some_folder_with_{special}_character_they_[name]`:
```

```bat
cmd /v/s/c "del /q /f "%%~dpnxi*.*" && rmdir /q "%%~dpnxi" && echo\Deleted:"%%~dpnxi"
```

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_mp3dir=F:\SUPER_USER\Q1507690\Organize"
set "_filter=%temp%\_filter_audio_!random!.log"

set "_audios=aa3,aac,aif,flac,m3u,m4a,mka,mp3,mpa,mpc,oga,ogg,pla,wav,wma"
type nul >"!_filter!" && for %%i in (!_audios!)do >>"!_filter!" echo=.%%~i

for /d /r "%_mp3dir%" %%i in (*)do tree /a /f "%%~fi"|find "\-" >nul || set "_rm_dir=yEp" && (for /f tokens^=* %%# in ('
     2^>nul %__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~dpnxi:*"')do type "!_filter!" | find /i "%%~x#" >nul && set "_rm_dir=nOp"
     if "!_rm_dir!"=="yEp" cmd /v/s/c "echo\del /q /f "%%~dpnxi\*.*" && echo\rmdir /q "%%~dpnxi" && echo\Deleted:"%%~dpnxi"
     )

set "_filter="<nul & del /q /f "%temp%\_filter_audio_*.log" & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

Test and if its seems zOk to you, just remove this **<strike>`echo`</strike>** command below:

```bat
if "!_rm_dir!"=="yEp" cmd /v/s/c "echo\del /q /f "%%~dpnxi*.*" && echo\rmdir /q "%%~dpnxi" && echo\Deleted:"%%~dpnxi"
```

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_mp3dir=F:\Organize"
set "_filter=%temp%\_filter_audio_!random!.log"

set "_audios=aa3,aac,aif,flac,m3u,m4a,mka,mp3,mpa,mpc,oga,ogg,pla,wav,wma"
type nul >"!_filter!" && for %%i in (!_audios!)do >>"!_filter!" echo=.%%~i

for /d /r "%_mp3dir%" %%i in (*)do tree /a /f "%%~fi"|find "\-" >nul || set "_rm_dir=yEp" && (for /f tokens^=* %%# in ('
     2^>nul %__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~dpni:*"')do type "!_filter!" | find /i "%%~x#" >nul && set "_rm_dir=nOp"
     if /i "!_rm_dir!" == "yEp" echo\rmdir /q "%%~dpni" ^&^& Folder: "%%~dpni" was deleted^!!
    )

set "_filter="<nul & del /q /f "%temp%\_filter_audio_*.log" & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

1. Define (`set`) all the necessary extensions to keep your audio files in the folder tree:

```bat
set "_audios=aa3,aac,aif,flac,m3u,m4a,mka,mp3,mpa,mpc,oga,ogg,pla,wav,wma"
```

2. Save all extensions in a file to use with `findstr` when checking the output of the listing for each folder (the last one at each level), using a `for` loop in the `_audios` variable previously defined:

```bat
type nul >"!_filter!" && for %%i in (!_audios!)do >>"!_filter!" echo=.%%~i
```

3. Use a specific loop for folders and recursive (`for /d /r`) at the same time checking if the current folder in the loop is the last folder at the current level (`tree ..|find "\-"`)that is, without subfolder below...

```bat
for /d /r "%_mp3dir%" %%i in (*)do tree /a /f "%%~fi"|find "\-" >nul
```

**Note:** This method is explained in detail in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1550103/trying-to-create-a-bat-file-to-copy-single-file-into-a-folder-that-contains-mult/1550282#1550282)**

4. Use a `for /f` loop additional to list files at the last level of each subfolder, and with the `where` command redirecting the file extension to the `find` to search the log file for the occurrence.

```bat
(for /f tokens^=* %%# in ('
     2^>nul %__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~dpni:*"')do type "!_filter!" | find /i "%%~x#" >nul
```

5. When `find` command finds an audio extension at the output of the loop, the variable `_rm_dir` will change the string from `yEp` to `nOp`, preventing the current folder from being deleted/removed, and when the opposite happens, where no existing file or none with an audio extension, the variable will keep the value of `_rm_dir` for `yEp`.

```bat
set "_rm_dir=yEp" && (for /f tokens^=* %%# in ('
     2^>nul %__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~dpni:*"')do type "!_filter!" | find /i "%%~x#" >nul && set "_rm_dir=nOp"
```

6. After the previous loop is finished, `if` will take the action (if necessary) to delete/remove the folder without audio files, when the condition is true for the comparison of variable `_rm_dir` equal to string `yEp`:

```bat
if /i "!_rm_dir!" == "yEp" echo\rmdir /q "%%~dpni" ^&^& Folder: "%%~dpni" was deleted^!!
```

7. Test and check the output, if it looks correct, just remove the `echo\` and specific 
   `^` from `^&^&`:

```bat
if /i "!_rm_dir!" == "yEp" echo\rmdir /q "%%~dpni" ^&^& Folder: "%%~dpni" was deleted^!!
```

8. The `echo` command is to give you a preview of the actions resulting from the script

```bat
if /i "!_rm_dir!" == "yEp" echo\rmdir /q "%%~dpni" ^&^& Folder: "%%~dpni" was deleted^!!
```

9. **`[Refer to the Update]`** To use your command to delete folders with a special character in the name, just invoke `cmd` with flag `/s`:

```bat
cmd /v/s/c "del /q /f "%%~dpnxi*.*" && rmdir /q "%%~dpnxi" && echo\Deleted:"%%~dpnxi"
```

```bat
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\540x21" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\540x21" was deleted
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\54x320" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\54x320" was deleted
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\12x349" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\12x349" was deleted
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\543x21" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\543x21" was deleted
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\123x45" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\123x45" was deleted
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\12x346" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\12x346" was deleted
rmdir /q "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\empty_" && Folder: "F:\SUPER_USER\Q1553051\Organize\empty_" was deleted
```

But, please consider paying attention to the comment @somebadhat:
*Rename `F:\!Organize` to `F:\Organize`*

Try to rename your folder by removing `!`, even if only for running this script.

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

  [√] **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[What is cmd /s for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866962/what-is-cmd-s-for)** // **⇉ Update**

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I'm still having an issue similar to what Pimp Juice IT provided when running both of yours, in which folders with characters such as `{ [` and other similar characters still exist after running the script. Here is an imgur link of what I see in my resulting test folder. https://i.imgur.com/ttNA0oT.png

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell:

Using the `-LiteralPath` parameter with `Remove-Item` alllows it to handle special characters in the name.

```
$Source = 'F:\Organize'
$KeepExts = '.mp3', '.flac', '.wav'

# Directories with files to keep
$Keep = gci $Source -file -recurse |
   Where Extension -in $KeepExts |
      Select -expand DirectoryName -unique

# Directories with no subfolders
$LeafDirs = gci $Source -dir -Recurse |
   Where { (!(gci $_.FullName -dir)) } |
      select -expand FullName

$ToDelete = $LeafDirs | Where { $_ -notIn $Keep }

Remove-Item -LiteralPath $ToDelete -recurse
```