# Remove sub-directories from multiple parent folders

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I have this situation

I'm in `C:\appfolder`, inside this directory I have some folders like

```
C:\appfolder
     |
   folder1
       |
       + subfolder1
       + file.png

   folder2
       |
       + subfolder2
       + subfolder3
       + file2.png

..
```

From `folder1, folder2..` I want to remove

```
subfolder1
subfolder2
subfolder3
...
```

I try this solution from CMD

```
for /R "C:\appfolder" %G in (*.*) do @echo %~tG "%~G"
```

and also from batch

```
for /R "C:\appfolder" %%G in (*.*) do @echo %%~tG "%%~G"
```

but doesn't work. Any idea to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an adapted/ported version of your question which is based on a very similar [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1550103/trying-to-create-a-bat-file-to-copy-single-file-into-a-folder-that-contains-mult/1550282#1550282) and in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1550282/969781) you have an explanation about the "mechanics" applied in getting the last subfolder in the tree...

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" & for /d /r %%i in (*)do ( 
     tree /a "%%~fi" | find "\-" >nul || rmdir "%%~fi\."
    )
```